# EventSource addEventListener callback method is not called when event comes from Django server

Tags: javascript, django, server-sent-events, http-streaming, eventsource

EventSource addEventListener callback is not called when event comes

Settings:
Django 2.0.7
Chrome 67.0.3396.99
MacOSX 10.13.6 (17G65)

Source code:
In my chat.html:

```
<script src="{% static 'django_eventstream/json2.js' %}" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'django_eventstream/eventsource.min.js' %}" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'chat/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}" charset="utf-8}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var testPubSub = function(user) {
        var uri = 'events/?channel=room-' + encodeURIComponent('{{ room_id }}');
        var es = new EventSource(uri, {
          lastEventId: '{{ last_id }}'
        });

        var firstConnect = true;

        es.onopen = function() {
          if (!firstConnect) {
            console.log('*** Connected');
          }
          firstConnect = false;
        }

        es.onerror = function() {
          console.log('*** connection lost');
        };

        console.log('before addEventListener');

        es.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
          console.log('addEventListener event');
          console.log('event: ' + e.data);
          msg = JSON.parse(e.data);

          console.log();
        }, false);
        console.log('after addEventListener');

        $('#send-form').submit(function() {
          var text = $('#chat-input').val();
          $.post('/rooms/{{ room_id }}/messages/', {from: user, text: text}
          ).done(function(data) {
            console.log('send response:' + JSON.stringify(data));
          }).fail(function() {
            alert('failed to send message');
          }).always(function() {
            $('#chat-input').val('');
            $('#chat-input').focus();
          });

          return false;
        });

        $('#chat-input').focus();
      };

      $(function() {
        testPubSub('{{ user|escapejs }}');
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chat-input-area">
      <form id="send-form">
        <button id="send-button">Send</button>
        <span id="chat-input-span"><input type="text" id="chat-input" autocomplete="off" /></span>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
```

From console log, I can see that when I push the send button, the following log is printed:

`before addEventListener
after addEventListener
send response:"333"`

but `addEventListener event` is not printed in the log.

From HTTP packets, I can see that Django server has sent the HTTP packet with 'event: ' in it:

`POST /publish/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5561
User-Agent: python-requests/2.19.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 130
JS Objection Notation:
{"items": [{"http-stream": {"content-filters": [], "content": "event: message\ndata: \"333\"\n\n"}, "channel": "events-room-r1"}]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the reason myself.

The `addEventListener` is OK. Something is wrong with my route configuration in Django(curiously, Django does not complain at all).

I used heavy log printing to pinpoint the root cause and after I reconfigured my routing in Django, the problem is solved.